# How can I change the data in TDengine?

Tags: database, time-series, tdengine

I'm using TDengine database for collected sensor data. Sometimes, there will be some error in collected data, and they will be also stored in the database. The data is inserted by timestamp.

How can I change them when I found the error?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot if your database option is 0, but you can update the data by using

```
insert into dbname.tableName values(timestamp_value, col1_value, ...)
```

if your database option is 1 or 2. just keep in mind that the timestamp_value should keep the same with the data you want to update.